# SQL Server EXECUTE AS on FN_TRACE_GETTABLE

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, permissions

I'm trying to allow a user to view SQL Server trace data from a .trc file without giving them `ALTER TRACE` permissions (SQL Server 2008 R2).  So I've wrapped it up in a stored procedure, using my sysadmin account:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test_trace
as
SELECT * FROM FN_TRACE_GETTABLE(N'C:\temp\trace1.trc', 1)
```

If I execute this stored procedure using my sysadmin account, it runs fine as expected.  If I try to run this under the domain1\user1 account, it does not run giving an error of `"You do not have permission to run 'FN_TRACE_GETTABLE'"`.  This is again expected.

So now I want to let `domain1\user1` run the stored procedure, so I change the stored procedure to execute under a sysadmin account:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test_trace 
WITH EXECUTE AS 'domain1\sysadmin1'
as
SELECT * FROM FN_TRACE_GETTABLE(N'C:\temp\trace1.trc', 1)
```

Now when I execute the stored procedure, I get `"You do not have permission to run 'FN_TRACE_GETTABLE'"` regardless of the account I execute it under!  I was expecting to be able to execute it both under the `domain1\user1` and `domain1\sysadmin1` accounts.

Could anybody please help with what I've missed?  My goal is to allow `domain1\user1` to read the `trace1.trc` file without giving them `ALTER TRACE` permissions.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [code signing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345102%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to elevate privileges in a controlled manner. While in an EXECUTE AS procedure context you are sandboxed and cannot leverage a server level priviledge (such as trace related permissions), read [Extending Database Impersonation by Using EXECUTE AS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188304%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). Code signing is the proper solution to this problem as well. See a [full example here](http://rusanu.com/2006/03/01/signing-an-activated-procedure/).

Comment: Thanks for the responses so far!


@Yve - I've got the domain1\user1 and domain1\sysadmin1 Server Logins mapped to Database users with the same name, so that shouldn't matter in this case.  I tried specifying EXECUTE AS SELF as you suggested, and I got the exact same result :-(  I also tried giving full control of the file to everyone (to eliminate any permissions-based issues), and again no joy.




@ Remus Rusanu - Thanks for those links.  I was looking for some more in-depth stuff about this kind of thing and this looks great

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms188354.aspx) you can only specify a (database) username in `execute as` for stored procedures. Still I think this should normally work, but please alter the SP with the sysadmin account and specify `EXECUTE AS SELF` instead of the user name.

If that still does not work, try giving the executing user read rights on the trace file, maybe the server ignores the `execute as` for the file access (which I would consider as a bug).

Comment: `maybe the server ignores the execute as for the file access (which I would consider as a bug).`: actually the bug would be if SQL Server can somehow miraculously conjure an access token without ever presenting a password to the local security authority... so no, EXECUTE AS has absolutely 0 (zero) meaning outside the realm of SQL Server itself and the OS will never trust it. If you want access to an outside resource you need to create a [CREDENTIAL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189522.aspx) and notice how you **must** present a secret (the account password).

Answer (score 0):

Copy&paste the path into a new explorer window and if it gives an error, there's your problem.  Took me a while to figure out why SQL Server said the "sa" account didn't have permissions that it did have.